# MLE of Poisson distribution with new observation

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ are i.i.d. observations from a Poisson distribution with

$$f_{\lambda}x = \frac{\lambda ^ x \exp^{-\lambda}} {x!}$$
for $x = 1,2,...,n.$

I have found the MLE of $\lambda$ : $\hat \lambda = \bar X.$

I am then asked to

1) Find the MLE of the probability that a new observation from the underlying distribution is equal to 1 by using the invariance property of the MLE.

2) Find the MLE of the probability that a new observation from the underlying distribution is greater than or equal to $1$.

How can I solve these two?

Answer (score 0):

The invariance property of the MLE says that if $\hat \theta$ is an MLE of $\theta$, then $f(\hat\theta)$ is an MLE of $f(\theta)$ if $f$ is a one-to-one function.

If $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, then what is $\Pr[X = 1]$ as a function of the unknown parameter $\lambda$?  Is this function one-to-one?

What is $\Pr[X \ge 1]$?  Is this function also one-to-one?

Comment: both of these are one to one, so the first MLE is $ \bar X e ^ {- \bar X}$, the second one is $1 - e ^ {- \bar X}$, am I right?

Comment: @Cindy How do you claim that the function $f(x) = x e^{-x}$ is one to one?  Have you tried sketching its graph or calculating its derivative?

Comment: since it's not one to one, I just maximize the function $\lambda e ^ \lambda$ with respect to $\lambda$ so MLE is $\hat \lambda = 1$?

Comment: so the MLE for the function is e??